# MySQL returns string with '\'

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I am using mysql and PHP.
The user are asked to input txt in textbox. I saved the string in mysql table, using mysql_real_escape_string($mystring). When I checked it in db, it has "prepended" \ whenever there is ' . Users are also allowed to edit the text, so I need to display the text in a html textarea. How do I skip the \ ? mysql_real_escape_string doesn't seem to work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have to use search. the question has been asked many times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds like `magic_quotes_gpc` might be turned on in your config. Check your php.ini file for this setting.

If you don't have access to `php.ini`, you can modify this setting in a .htaccess file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

When it comes to updating the existing value, try using `htmlentities` to escape the funny characters.

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentites($value); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. However, stripslashes() worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I will also try magic_quotes_gpc since you said it is better to use. Thanks a lot!